# xamarin.forms UWP navigation cooperation with native navigation

Tags: win-universal-app, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms Pages and than open a Native page XPage1->XPage2->XPage3->NativePage

and if i do on the native page

```
Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
        rootFrame.GoBack();
```

i end up on XPage1

any ideas how to convince the navigation to work normaly and go to XPage3?